# Nativescript Drawer Navigation bidirectional data binding

Tags: angular, nativescript

I am creating new app that uses template with drawer navigation

```
tns create HelloWorld --template tns-template-drawer-navigation-ng
```

Next, following the online tutorial i am testing bidirectional data binding. Following the example, onthe home page, I have one TextField which binds to email field using [(ngModel)]="email" and button (tap)=signUp(), also i have added NativeScriptFormsModule to the NgModule’s list of imports. For some reason the bidirectional data binding doesn't work only one way. Does anybody faced similar issue?

Comment: Have you imported `NativeScriptFormsModule` in the respective `NgModule` file - https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/core-concepts/angular-data-binding#data-binding

Comment: yes I did, and this is why i find it very strange of not working.

Comment: Try using `[text]="myValue" (textChange)="onTextChange($event)" ` as shown here https://github.com/NativeScript/nativescript-sdk-examples-ng/blob/master/app/ui-category/text-field/text-field-binding/text-field-binding.component.html#L4

Comment: ok i will try that but still this doesnt make sense ... the grocery app is working fine with the above format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can find a [PlayGround demo](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-ng&id=uJuCka) for creating two-way binding on `TextField` with `ngModel` - use it as reference to compare it with your code base

Comment: whilst this is not exactly the answer to the question, which was to include the NativeScriptFormsModule  in the actual page module (not only the whole application) it pointed me to the right direction. thx